# How to find the next free slot for an appointment with Outlook for Mac 16?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In other versions of Outlook the room finder also suggests free time slots. Apart from the fact that it's a teams meeting and I don't need a room, even if I add a room, the room finder doesn't suggest a free time.

Answer (score 0):

What other versions of outlook do you mention?

Based on my research on Outlook for mac(version is as shown in the below figure), the suggested time can't be found too, which is the same issue with yours. I'm afraid that it's by design.
[image]

However, it's suggested that you could check the free/busy information shown in the scheduling grid. For more information about room finder, please refer to: [Room Finder opens in the scheduling page of your meeting invitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-a-conference-room-1d1c576f-c6e8-4c80-b200-9f55a940ca1f#:%7E:text=Room%20Finder%20opens%20in%20the%20scheduling%20page%20of%20your%20meeting%20invitation.).
[image]